# Cutting out an unnecessary part of url in angular router

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm making an application with login and signup pages. They both share quite a lot of things, that I want to put in a component called auth-component.

The component hierarchy is:

```
app-component
    auth-component
        login-component
        signup-component
    other-component
```

But since `mypage.com/auth` alone is not used for anything, I'd rather cut that part out, and have URL:s `mypage.com/login` and `mypage.com/signup`, without the 'auth' in the middle.

Currently, the ways to do this that I can come up with are:

1. Hard-code 'auth' into both login-component and signup-component, which goes against DRY (especially when there are more than two components)
2. Using mypage.com/:keyword that loads the auth-component, which in turn contains

   `<app-login *ngIf="currentRoute==='login'"></app-login>`

   `<app-signup *ngIf="currentRoute==='signup'"></app-signup>`

which I think is a really ugly hack, since both login and signup are existing pages, and not some key-values.

I feel like this should be a fairly common problem, so there should be a standard way of doing it? Or am I thinking about it entirely wrong, and the whole page should be structured entirely differently?

I found one similar question from long ago, with no answer, so I hope it's okay to post this.

Comment: If `/auth` is not used for anything, what does `AuthComponent` do? Maybe it should be a parent class of both components instead?

Comment: That would be a good solution, but I cannot have <app-auth><router-outlet></router-outlet></app-auth>, since there are other pages that shouldn't have AuthComponent as their parent. I've updated the hierarchy in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auth-component` doesn't need to be a route. All you need to do is following:

1. let /login route to LoginComponent and /signup route to SignupComponent
2. Create the AuthComponent that yields all the common frame stuff. At the place where both components differ, place the `<ng-content></ng-content>` "placeholder".
3. Within the LoginComponent and Signupcomponent you use AuthComponent while specifying the content

login-component:

```
<auth-component>
  ...login-stuff
</auth-component>
```

login-stuff goes where ng-content was defined.

Answer (score 0):

So, after returning to this problem a few times, and quite some research and trying, I have found what I think is the most "proper" way of doing this. I thought I'd post it here, in case others run into the same problem.

The answer that I accepted before works in many cases, but can be hard to combine with things like animations, and I think it reloads the parent on every page change. It also feels a bit wrong, because in some sense, the parent is a part of each child.

This problem can be solved by making a [custom serializer](https://lukeliutingchun.medium.com/angular-introduction-to-named-router-outlet-and-a-hack-for-custom-url-6ca1cd11fd2a), which was my first solution. It works well, but it feels like a hack in this case, and is probably slightly less effective.

**What I think is a better way** is using a custom matcher in a router module. In my case, I created an `auth-routing.module.ts` file, containing the routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: authMatcher,
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

with the authMatcher function

```
const authMatcher = (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
  if (url.length > 0) {
    const path = url[0].path;
    return path === 'login' ||
      path === 'signup'
      ? { consumed: [] }
      : null;
  }
  return null;
};
```

The [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) for the UrlMatcher is not very thorough, but the trick is returning an empty array as consumed, and null if no match was found. In that case, angular router sends the same URL to the children, and no UrlSegment is consumed. This approach also has the added benefit that authComponent is inaccessible in itself, without LoginComponent or SignupComponent. No exception for `/auth` is needed (as would be the case with a custom serializer).

In the documentation, the whole url is returned as consumed, which means that the router stops there, and nothing is sent to the children. In this case, only an empty authComponent would be shown. This is not explained there, and confused me for some time.